# In App Purchase Got SKErrorDomain Code=0 - 'Cannot connect Itunes store' - when click cancel in prompt sigin

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit, swiftystorekit

I got below Error

> SKErrorDomain Code=0 - 'Cannot connect Itunes store'

When click Cancel option in prompt sig in. It work well if i use existing apple ID or create new apple ID. Please help :(
[Promp Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCHBn.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community  -Thank you

Comment: Have you tried logging in, in the iOS settings app

Comment: Nothing happens if I have logged in iTunes in-app setting. But if I log out then log in again I still got that error :(